# Windows-Terminal commands to have information about LaTeX distribution

Tags: installing, distributions

I'm looking for command to use in one terminal so as to know the following facts.

1. Is there one LaTeX distribution installed ?
2. What is the path where to put local classes or packages ? In my Mac, I know that it is `'/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex'`.

The command will be used by one Python script so as to automate the installation of my personnal little classes or packages.

The solutions given in the following comments work well on Mac, and I think that this works also under Linux, **but I don't know how to do under Windows**...

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME`, which will tell you where to 'local install' material?

Comment: And on a Mac, @JosephWright 's command returns `/Users/<name>/Library/texmf` not `usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/` which is for system wide local additions. For that you need to use `--var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` (which on a current Mac installation returns `/usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Which of course you should not be adding anything to :-)

Comment: Thanks. This works well on Mac. But what about Linux and Windows ? There is also still the first point to be solved...

Comment: @projetmbc If you have a TeX distribution installed, you have `kpsewhich`; if you don't have one you won't have it.  I don't think there's a surefire way to check that a distribution is 'complete' (if that's even a well formed idea), but just testing for the existence of the TeX binaries should be enough to verify that you have one.

Comment: @AlanMunn : you're right. I'll do like this.

Comment: @projetmbc To check for a TeX system, I'd probably do `which pdftex` on Unix and use a path search on Windows (we have some code for this in the LaTeX3 build scripts to find Perl). However, this is more about shell scripting than TeX: the same approach applies to any executable you want to find.

Comment: @JosephWright : thanks for the `which`.

Comment: @JosephWright: In Windows, the `which` counterpart command is `where`: it will list all entries found in the `PATH` (I believe it looks only for files with extensions mapped in the `PATHEXT` variable which can be executed in the command prompt and their order). `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of finding the correct location for a local installation, we do this in the `make.bat` files for LaTeX3. There, we have

```
if not defined TEXMFHOME (
  for /f "delims=" %%I in ('kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME') do @set TEXMFHOME=%%I
  if [%TEXMFHOME%] == [] (
    set TEXMFHOME=%USERPROFILE%\texmf
  )
```

which means that if the variable `TEXMFHOME` exists then it is used, otherwise we try `kpsewhich` to get a value, and if that returns nothing fall-back on the default location.

---

For finding 'some program', I use another bit of batch file programming culled from elsewhere. Here, the example is to find Perl, but the same approach would apply to finding pdfTeX

```
:perl

  set PATHCOPY=%PATH%

:perl-loop

  if defined PERLEXE goto :end

  for /f "delims=; tokens=1,2*" %%I in ("%PATHCOPY%") do (
    if exist %%I\perl.exe set PERLEXE=perl
    set PATHCOPY=%%J;%%K
  )

  if defined PERLEXE goto :end

  if not "%PATHCOPY%"==";" goto :perl-loop

  echo.
  echo  This procedure requires Perl, but it could not be found.

  exit /b 1

  goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope I did not missunderstand the question.

For Windows I simply would try with `pdftex --version` or `pdflatex --version` in the command line. If there is a (proper) installed version of TeX you get the Name of the distribution and the version.

You can also use `path` to see, if there is a directory for the binaries of TeX (MiKTex or TeXLive).

`kpsewhich` is running on windows, but has different parameters to the unix version (see comments of @Joseph Wright and @Alan Munn).

Comment: `kpsewhich` works on both Unix and Windows in the same way (see the LaTeX3 build scripts). I would avoid using `pdftex --version` as you get an error if it's not found, whereas a search can be done for the appropriate path without issuing an error if it fails.

Comment: I only use `kpsewhich` to find a location _if needed_. If a value is not known, out scripts make the assumption on Windows to use `%USERPROFILE%\texmf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the version of LaTex, pdfTex or packages you can check the log file in any project you've compiled on the system and there it is. There you'll also be able to see the path of the different packages and from there deduce the path of your executable TeX file